# I get this error when I click on links in webview page

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I get this error when I click on links in webview page, error part =

```
throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage as String?, 
     details: 
       errorDetails, stacktrace: errorStacktrace);
        } else {
          throw const FormatException('Invalid envelope');
          }
```

Comment: Kindly Share some more peace of code for better understanding

Comment: What you show is not an error you get, but one you throw yourself.

Comment: Please provide more details what you are trying yo achieve.  [Take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), You need to provide [provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: when i press it it takes me to the class of this error

Comment: There are different pages and links in the webview when I click on the links I get this error

Answer (score 0):

You must [specify minSdkVersion 19 or higher](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#using-hybrid-composition) or [use AndroidWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#using-hybrid-composition) for android. Read more https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
  }
}
```

or

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Enable virtual display.
  if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
}
```

Comment: i used these but it didn't work

Comment: The source of the problem =                                                                                                      
                           if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();